# How can I deploy this C# code as a standalone file (equivalent to a .exe) on a Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I have a requirement for a small app which the user would download from the web and run on their Mac. The purpose of this is to set a value in an xml file on their local machine. (It is for Parallels - basically the script will read their Mac serial number, and set it as the serial number of the virtual machine under /users//Parallels/.pvm/config.pvs.)

I am fairly adept at programming on Windows, but new to programming for Mac. If I was doing this on Windows I would write a small C# EXE which the user could download and run.

This is the code I have so far:

```
string serialNumber;
using (var p = new Process())
{
    var serialRegex = new Regex("\"IOPlatformSerialNumber\" = \"(\\S+)\"");
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/sbin/ioreg",
                                       "-c IOPlatformExpertDevice");
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    serialNumber = serialRegex.Match(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()).Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
    p.WaitForExit();
}

Console.WriteLine("The following Virtual Machines were detected. Please enter the nunber of the Windows installation you plan to use as your Analysys Mason virtual machine.");

var profilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
var parallelsDir = Path.Combine(profilePath, "Parallels");

bool carryOn = false;

int i = 1;

string[] vms = Directory.GetDirectories(parallelsDir, "*.pvm").OrderByDescending(f => f).ToArray();

foreach (var vm in vms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + ". " + vm.Split('/').Last());
    i++;
}
int index = 0;

while (!carryOn) {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the Virtual Machine");
    var entry = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);


    if (Int32.TryParse(entry, out index)) {
        if (index > 0 && index <= vms.Length){
            carryOn = true;
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number of a virtual machine from the list above");
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("You selected: " + vms[index - 1]);
```

This works from Visual Studio, but I have no idea how to deploy it as a standalone executable file.

How can I package it so that I can put it somewhere a user can download and run it?

My preference would be to make a GUI app (similar to a WinForms or XAML app). How can I do this from Visual Studio / Xamarin?

Comment: You could run a program a mac with .net core all you need is to create self contained application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#self-contained-application

Comment: @Gabriel That code could need to be adapted to core tho, check the ".net core notes" section in [Console class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: "How can I do this from Visual Studio / Xamarin?" Unless I am missing more recent news, looks like Xamarin.Forms for MAC is still in preview. https://blog.xamarin.com/preview-bringing-macos-to-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @bradbury9 - so if I'm reading that right, that means that whilst I can currently only make a Xamarin forms app for Android / iOS, it should (soon) allow me to make a MacOS app too. Are these deployable in the way I describe above or do they need to go through the respective App stores?

Comment: No clue, im not much into Xamarin

Comment: You only need Xamarin if you want to write a Mac Desktop app.  If this is just a console app it can be done with .NET core.

Comment: @Ben You could do this via a shell script and avoid the native compile phase of either a .Net Core or Xamarin.Mac app.

Comment: @Jason - ideally I'd like to put a GUI in front of it eventually. Starting with it as a console app so I'm not trying to run before I can walk. (Turns out walking is a struggle though!!)

Comment: Having a hard dependency on .NET for such a simple utility seems really strange. Moving to Xamarin will bloat the size of your executable (which can be fine, but doesn't seem justified in this case). This would be trivial to implement in Objective C or Swift. Maybe a good excuse to learn the tools? You will produce a binary that's compact and can be run without the user installing any dependency.

Comment: @TheNextman - sounds like a plan. :-)